# Run function on multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, onload

I need to run a function on two cases.One when the page was loaded , and one each time the element was clicked.The click event works,but the onload one doesn't.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

var captcha;

    $('#captcha').on('ready click',function(){
        function alphanumeric_unique() {
            return Math.random().toString(36).split('').filter( function(value, index, self) { 
                return self.indexOf(value) === index;
            }).join('').substr(2,8);
        }

        captcha = alphanumeric_unique();

        $(this).val(captcha);
    });
});


<input type="text" readonly value="" id="captcha">
```

Any help please?

Comment: Make it into a function. Then call the function on load, and assign it to the event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger click event on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $('#captcha').on('click',function(){
        function alphanumeric_unique() {
            return Math.random().toString(36).split('').filter( function(value, index, self) { 
                return self.indexOf(value) === index;
            }).join('').substr(2,8);
        }

        captcha = alphanumeric_unique();

        $(this).val(captcha);
    });

    $('#captcha').trigger("click"); // it will automatically call click event


});
```

Comment: yeah it works in my case , thanks .But still , for my knowledge , can i use two events , in particular click and onload ? Because i tried anything i could come up with and didn't managed to solve it.

Comment: as per my knowlegde..no you can bind load event also with click event..you will have to use trigger event to call any click event

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the function outside the click event. Then you can call it on the page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var captcha = alphanumeric_unique();
  $('#captcha').on('ready click', function() {
    captcha = alphanumeric_unique();
    $(this).val(captcha);
  });
});

function alphanumeric_unique() {
  return Math.random().toString(36).split('').filter(function(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  }).join('').substr(2, 8);
}
```

If you put the function inside the click event, then the scope will be restricted to that event handler only.

Answer (score 1):

Just set your function separately and use it on any event you like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function alphanumeric_unique() {
        return Math.random().toString(36).split('').filter( function(value, index, self) { 
            return self.indexOf(value) === index;
        }).join('').substr(2,8);
    }
    var captcha = alphanumeric_unique();
    $('#captcha').on('click',function(){
        $(this).val(captcha = alphanumeric_unique());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the functionality like so:

```
function alphanumeric_unique() {
  return Math.random().toString(36).split('').filter( function(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
  }).join('').substr(2,8);
}

function update_captcha() {
  $('#captcha').val(alphanumeric_unique());
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  // Update when document is ready
  update_captcha();
  // Update when captcha is clicked
  $('#captcha').click(update_captcha);
});
```